# Корректно ли написание «исполком МОК»?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

Корректно ли — с маленькой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это сокращение официального наименования элемента структуры МОК, причём в полном наименовании "**Исполнительный комитет МОК**" сокращаемое слово находится *в начале* и пишется с большой. То же самое происходит с сокращениями названий миниcтерств (Минздрав и т. п.).

Для сравнения: слово "*комсомол*" пишется с маленькой буквы, поскольку полное наименование организации "Всероссийский..." ("Всесоюзный...") начинается с другого слова и "коммунистический" пишется с маленькой буквы - это неформальное сокращение.

Соответственно, при формальных ссылках на этот орган: **Исполком МОК**.